# Move the mouse in a Canvas and display a point moving in the same way BUT in another canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm creating an interface with Tkinter (Python3) having two canvas. I want to moove the mouse over one canvas and to display a dot moving in the same way (as the mouse) but in the other canva.

I have tried this :

```
    def motion(self,event):
            x, y = event.x, event.y
            self.dot=self.canvas.create_oval((x,y), (x,y), width=2, outline='red', fill='red')
```

The problem is that I can display the point but this one will remain. I have also tried to delete the dot after creating it, but this way it will not apprear :

```
    def motion(self,event):
            x, y = event.x, event.y
            self.dot=self.canvas.create_oval((x,y), (x,y), width=2, outline='red', fill='red')
            self.canvas.delete(self.dot)
```

Can someone help me ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create a new dot each time the mouse moves. Create the dot once and move it around with the canvas method `coords(<item>, *new_coords)`. `<item>` is the canvas item id returned by `create_oval` (an int).

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def on_move(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    canvas2.coords(dot, x - 5, y - 5, x + 5, y + 5)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas2 = tk.Canvas(root, bg='white')

canvas1.pack(side='left')
canvas2.pack(side='right')
dot = canvas2.create_oval(-10, -10, 0, 0, fill='black')

canvas1.bind('<Motion>', on_move)

root.mainloop()
```